# Where can I live if I like long periods of consistent rain?

Tags: meteorology, climate, rainfall

Let me elaborate on what I mean by "long periods of consistent rain".

I currently live in London and contrary to popular belief, it's not rainy. When it rains, it's usually only for 20 minutes and mixed with sunshine on the same day. I miss proper rainy days like in Paarl, South Africa where it rains for the whole day and stays grey.

I want to live somewhere where I can experience multiple days like this in a row, many times a year. And preferably, when the sun shines it should also be thoroughly sunny for many days in a row.

So basically, I want the opposite of London's weather. I don't want the weather to change multiple times in one day. I want long periods of sunshine and long periods of heavy rain, each lasting days on end.

Where can I find a climate like this?

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They are many regions with rain and drought seasons, but not in Europe.

Comment: @LShaver meteorology is listed as one of the subjects for this site